# Weight argument of Loss Function

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

Suppose I have a training set which consists of 4 classes and the number of samples belonging to the 4 classes is 20, 30, 40, 10 respectively. So should I pass the tensor torch.tensor([20,30,40,10]) / 100. to the weight argument of the loss function?
Or should I calculate the values of the weight argument for each batch on the fly in the training loop?

Answer (score 0):

For most use cases, you will not need to specify the weight argument - in your example, you should leave the weight unset (i.e. `weight=None`).

You only need to specify class weights if your dataset is highly imbalanced. For example, if you have 99% positive examples and 1% negative examples, then you would want to assign higher weight to the negative samples to help the model learn.